# EB Garamond initials and hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, font-encodings, ebgaramond

Consider the following MWE (to be compiled with XeLaTeX):

```
% TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \textin{T}his is a test
\end{document}
```

It fails with

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textin unavailable in encoding TU.
```

Does anyone know to get around this?

Comment: @mico `\textin{T}` is fine. The bug is mixing Unicode and the T1 encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that hyperref redefines `\textin` to mean the symbol ∈ (U+2208), but only for the encoding used in the bookmarks.

If you want to keep the name (and don't need the symbol), overwrite the definition again after hyperref:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textin}{\initials}

\begin{document}
  \textin{T}his is a test
\end{document}
```

But probably it would be better if ebgaramond would use another name, e.g. `\textinitials`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, just a curiosity. Because using the editor https://cocalc.com/ (in my deleted answer) I see the "T"?

Comment: @Sebastiano you probably used pdflatex, but the question is about xelatex.

Comment: I don't now but using pdflatex or other engine with Papeeria I not see the "T" if I remember well.

Comment: Papeeria imho has a rather old tex system. If you want to try things online, better use latex online at learnlatex.org.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious suggestion. Papeeria have all the engines and TeXLive 2019. At the end...+1 for all. :-)